# Use dynamic value in Postman test script

Tags: testing, postman

I have a postman test script to use with test runner. I am trying to pass dynamic value from file  to validate response with no success. I am able to pass value to request, but not able to use value from data file in test script. I want to validate response with data passed from CSV file. Is something like below possible in first place?

```
pm.test("Body matches string", function () {

    pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include('{{$column1}}');

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that variable usage in test script is different. Below works.

```
pm.test("Body matches string", function () {

    pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include(pm.variables.get("column1"));

});
```